# Problem during translations in return view of an order

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, table, view

I've a multilanguages site in Magento 1.9. In return section there's a table and code of its head is the following:

```
<table class="data-table" id="my-returns-items-table">
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
                            <th class="condition"><?php echo $this->__('Condition') ?></th>
                            <th class="resolution"><?php echo $this->__('Resolution') ?></th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Request') ?></span></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Status') ?></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

'SKU' translation in the other languages don't shown and I don't know why. I inserted "SKU","Product" into translate.csv but the string that I see is "UGS". This don't happen for other attribute of tale head.
Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under certain conditions, translation keys need a module prefix.

1. Add the if-block below to method `_getTranslatedString()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php`.

   ```
   protected function _getTranslatedString($text, $code)
   {
       // ADD THIS BLOCK
       if ( $text == 'SKU' )
       {
           Mage::log('Translation key for SKU: '.$code, Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'sql_translation_key.log', true);
       }

       $translated = '';
       if (array_key_exists($code, $this->getData())) {
           $translated = $this->_data[$code];
       }
       elseif (array_key_exists($text, $this->getData())) {
           $translated = $this->_data[$text];
       }
       else {
           $translated = $text;
       }
       return $translated;
   }
   ```
2. Visit the page in question.
3. Check contents of `var/log/sql_translation_key.log`. You should see something like `Translation key for SKU: Module_Name::SKU`.
4. Use the latter as the key in your translate.csv so it looks similar to `"Module_Name::SKU","Product"`.
5. Remove the if-block

**Don't forget to disable translation cache while debugging.**